# Simple way to keep hard disk alive on activity?

Tags: hard-disk, power-management

As `hdparm` [does not work](https://superuser.com/q/868663/96128) for my USB external drive (it spins down too early), I’d like to simulate stand-by control manually by a simple script with the following idea:

- monitor I/O to the disk
- when, except for the script itself, there is no I/O from other processes for some time, produce dummy I/O to keep disk alive

  - after some time let drive spin down
  - the dummy I/O should at best be nothing that actually reads or writes to disk (and therefore moves the mechanics producing wear-out) but maybe read some status etc.

I’m not experienced enough in Bash scripting to know which commands could be used.
Any suggestions? The system is Arch Linux.

Comment: Does smartctl work? That is, does `smartctl -d sat --all` show disk info? If it does, there is -g option to modify apm settings.

Answer (score 1):

(I am aware this question is over 2 years old, however the problem is still actual)

I am using the following code for my drive that doesn't respect smartctl settings:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
        date +%s > /second_drive/keepalive_linux.txt
        sync
        sleep 2
done
```

To make it run at startup, I used:

```
EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

And added:

```
@reboot bash /path/to/script.sh
```

(the drive is NTFS formatted, by the way)

It is the same behaviour that [KeepAliveHD for Windows](https://github.com/stsrki/KeepAliveHD) has.

While it could be done in a better way (like the OP described), it's better than nothing for now.

Answer (score 0):

Google should get the credit for this one:

http://www.unix.com/programming/161666-tool-simulate-non-sequential-disk-i-o-simulate-db-file-sequential-read-c-posix.html

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((N=0; N<10; N++))
do
        dd if=gigabytefile of=/dev/null skip=$((RANDOM % 1024)) bs=$((1024*1024)) count=1
done
```

Comment: Sorry, but this seems completely unrelated.